# Where are Python headers included in MacOS Monterey arm64

Tags: c++, macos, apple-silicon

I am currently struggling to find the python headers on my system and can't include them therefore into a C++ application

this is my cmake file -->

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(ondoki-desktop VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /Users/ahoehne/repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)



set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED)





if(DEFINED ENV{VIRTUAL_ENV} OR DEFINED ENV{CONDA_PREFIX})
  set(_pip_args)
else()
  set(_pip_args "--user")
endif()

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ondoki-daemon
  GIT_REPOSITORY    "https://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@github.com/ondoki-org/ondoki-daemon.git"
  GIT_TAG           develop
  SOURCE_DIR        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ondoki-daemon"

  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""

)

execute_process(COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -m pip install -r ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ondoki-daemon/requirements.txt)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(ZeroMQ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(cppzmq CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS  )
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS filesystem regex REQUIRED)
find_package(msgpack CONFIG REQUIRED)

find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)




set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        qml.qrc
        images.qrc
        python.qrc
        zmqbridge.cpp
        zmqbridge.h
        zmqworker.h
        zmqworker.cpp
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(ondoki-desktop
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET ondoki-desktop APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(ondoki-desktop SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(ondoki-desktop
          ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_compile_definitions(ondoki-desktop
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(ondoki-desktop
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick
  protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite libzmq
          libzmq-static  nlohmann_json nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
          cppzmq cppzmq-static ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ¢{PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
          msgpackc msgpackc-cxx pybind11::lto pybind11::embed pybind11::module

  )

set_target_properties(ondoki-desktop PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_import_qml_plugins(ondoki-desktop)
    qt_finalize_executable(ondoki-desktop)
endif()
```

The Error message for including #include <pybind11/embed.h> is common.h Python.h not found

locate python.h results in

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/common/python.h
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/common/python.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/mpi/python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/arg_from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/arg_from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/obj_mgr_arg_from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/return_from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/shared_ptr_from_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/converter/shared_ptr_to_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python/register_ptr_to_python.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/python.hpp
```

/usr/local/include has no Python.h as has /opt/homebrew/include

a "which python3" results in /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

and my cmake parameters are the following

```
-GNinja
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
-DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE:PATH=%{IDE:ResourcePath}/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=%{Qt:qmakeExecutable}
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:C}
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:Cxx}
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/ahoehne/repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
%{CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:DefaultFlag}
```

Thank you for any help or hints into the right direction.

***EDIT ***

if i include

include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers)

at least he seems to find the header

but results in a "expected member name or ";" after declaration specifiers --> Following the object.h file I see

```
typedef struct{
    int slot;    /* slot id, see below */
    void *pfunc; /* function pointer */
} PyType_Slot;

typedef struct{
    const char* name;
    int basicsize;
    int itemsize;
    unsigned int flags;
    PyType_Slot *slots; /* terminated by slot==0. */
} PyType_Spec;
```

on the error code line ...if I remove PyType_Slot *slots; the program compiles but I highly doubt that this is a bug and rather a problem on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the first problem is with the order of these lines:

```
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED)
```

So you refer to an unknown yet `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable.

The second problem is the variable name itself. You are searching for Python3 package so to me the variable name should be `Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS` as per the [FindPython3 doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindPython3.html)

The 3rd problem is that you are searching for Interpreter only, so the headers will not be found anyway.

Summarising, please check if something like the following works:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer ---> Your answer is logical and helpful --> I again land on this error bt this seems to be a whole different problem --> Answer accepted /Users/ahoehne/repos/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/include/python3.10/object.h:227:23: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers PyType_Slot *slots; /* terminated by slot==0. */